# GStreamer split mp4 video by seconds with decodebin and splitmuxsink

Tags: c, gstreamer

With the example from gstreamer

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=audio/mario.mp4 ! queue ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! queue ! h264parse ! queue ! mux.video demux.audio_0 ! queue ! aacparse !  queue ! mux.audio_0 splitmuxsink location=audio/test//out_%d.mp4 max-size-time=10000000000 muxer=mp4mux name=mux
```

I am able to split the mp4 to several pieces. But when I change the qtdemux to decodebin, things change

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=audio/mario_00.mp4 ! decodebin name=demuxer ! queue ! video/x-raw ! videoconvert !  x264enc ! mux.video audio/x-raw ! queue ! audioconvert ! wavenc ! queue ! mux.audio_0 splitmuxsink location=audio/test/video%02d.mp4 max-size-time=10000000000 muxer=mp4mux name=mux
```

This give me error messages

```
GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 07:58:00.441: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "audio"
```

I change audio/x-raw to demuxer.audio/x-raw, demuxer.audio, demuxer.audio_0, they give me error messages

```
(gst-launch-1.0:11252): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 07:59:35.828: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: unexpected reference "demuxer" - ignoring
```

How could I split the mp4 after I change the qtdemux to decodebin?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your second command is incomplete. It does not make sense to have `h264parse` after `decodebin`.

Comment: Edited, I want to use decodebin to extract the video and audio to raw data and mux them into mp4, but it don't work

Comment: `mp4mux` does not support raw video as input at this time. Consider switching to `matroskamux` instead. You pipeline seems weird - why is there `x264enc` when you want raw video?

Comment: Thanks, raw video and audio are the results extracted by the decodebin, I want to encode video by different codec